# How to separate arrays into variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, variables

I've tried to look this up, but I'm not quite getting an answer that pertains directly to what I'm doing. I'm trying to retrieve values from a database that were previously submitted. I want to use these values to locate filepaths on the server and use the fillepath information to display the files. To do this, I need to separate the array that i have here. How would I separate this array?

```
$code = $_POST['codeInput'];


$code = htmlspecialchars($code); 


$submitCodes = "SELECT story,video FROM `storycodes` WHERE `code` = $codeInput";


$files = mysql_fetch_array($submitCodes); 

mysql_close($con);

print_r(array_values($files));
```

I appreciate any help guys. Ideally I would like to get a variable like $story or $storyPath and $video or $videoPath I need the video as a variable so I can play it with a video player.

EDIT:
I changed from mysql to mysqli and I'm getting all of these errors now that I can't seem to fix. I have the result set and it says I don't.

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/98/10339998/html/scripts/stories.php on line 26

I think this warning should fix itself once the array gets sorted out:

Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/content/98/10339998/html/scripts/stories.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/98/10339998/html/scripts/stories.php on line 30

```
$con = mysqli_connect("storycodes.db.10339998.hostedresource.com",$username,$password);

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($con, "storycodes");

$code = $_POST['codeInput'];


$code = htmlspecialchars($code); 

$query = "SELECT story,video FROM `storycodes` WHERE `code` = $codeInput";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

extract($row);  

mysqli_free_result($result); 
mysqli_close($con);

echo $story . $video;
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions for new projects.  They are deprecated in 5.5 and will be removed soon. Consider `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this

```
$files = mysql_fetch_array($submitCodes); 
extract( $files );

// now you can use it like this
echo $story . $video; // as variables
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Especially for the fast response. I hope this post will be of use for others with similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = mysql_fetch_assoc( $submitCodes );
extract( $files );
```